# Question on Egorov's Theorem: How do you find such $E_{\epsilon}$ sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

Egorov's Theorem is as follows: Let $X$ be a finite measure space.  If $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e., then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $E_{\epsilon}\subset X$ such that $m(E_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $X\setminus E_\epsilon$.

I don't have a specific problem in front of me, but suppose we had a problem where we were given some hypothesis, and we had to find such a $E_\epsilon$.  Is there a standard method to find such a set?  Could you maybe provide some examples?  I (believe I) understand the proof of Egorov's theorem, but I am having a hard time actually finding such sets, rather than just claiming such sets exist.  One last question: since $X$ is a finite measure space, then we can use $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure in the original claim, correct?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no "general" method to find these sets, Egorov's theorem just proves that they exist. For a loose strategy, if you have some functions $(f_n)_n$ which converge pointwise but not absolutely, typically they converge quite fast everywhere except a "small set". Finding a small set where $f_n$ takes "abnormal" values and removing it will make the $f_n$s converge uniformly. As an example, Consider the measure space $\big((0,1),\mathscr{L}_{(0,1)},\lambda\big)$ and the sequence of measurable functions $f_n(x)=x^n$. Then, $f_n\to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly. *However*, if we consider the Lesbesgue measurable set $(0,1-\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ then $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on this set. How did I choose this set? Well, if you look at the graph of say, $x^{20}$,

[image: graph]

Then you can see that it is really small for everything to the left of, say $0.8$, but it increases rapidly, i.e, is far away from zero, for the right little bit. So in this case you choose to remove the bit of the graph where $f_n$ is "far away" from zero.

Finally, something I'd like to clarify. Even on a finite measure space, $f_n\to f$ in measure does **NOT**, in general, imply uniform convergence. As a counterexample consider the sequence of simple functions $f_n=\mathbf{1}_{(0,1/n)}$. Then $f_n\to 0$ in measure, but not uniformly (check this!). So in your statement of Egorov's theorem, NO, you cannot swap out uniform convergence for convergence in measure, because they are not the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I do appreciate this!  I was saying, rather than swapping out uniform convergence, that we can swap out pointwise convergence with in measure convergence, because $X$ is a finite set.

Comment: @User7238 According to [this source](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/fall07/section2.4b.pdf), yes, convergence in measure does imply pointwise convergence in a finite measure space.

Comment: @K.defaoite -- I've edited your question to shrink the image, and removed your request that someone do so. If this isn't what you had in mind, feel free to undo my edits